# Accordion switching icon not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add to my accordion minus sign to appear after clicking on the row.

I've tried adding **minus/plus** let and tried to add display.styles for it. But it seems really buggy and not working properly. How can I set this up properly? And it only works for first element instead of all.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".faq__tab").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const tabsContent = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.classList.toggle('active-faq');
    let minus = document.querySelector(".plus")
    let plus = document.querySelector(".minus")

    if (button.classList.contains('active-faq')) {
      tabsContent.style.maxHeight = tabsContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
      plus.style.display = 'none';
      minus.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
      tabsContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
      minus.style.display = 'none';
      plus.style.display = 'flex';
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.plus {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.minus {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.faq__panel {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="faq__tab">Question
 <img src='img/plus.svg' alt="Show" class="plus">
 <img src='img/minus-svg.png' alt="Hide" class="minus">
</button>
<div class="faq__panel">
  <p>Answerr
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `inline-flex` instead of `flex`:

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".faq__tab").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const tabsContent = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.classList.toggle('active-faq');
    let minus = button.querySelector(".plus");//instead of document use button to target the corresponding element
    let plus = button.querySelector(".minus");//instead of document use button to target the corresponding element

    if (button.classList.contains('active-faq')) {
      tabsContent.style.maxHeight = tabsContent.scrollHeight + 'px';   
      minus.style.display = 'none';
      plus.style.display = 'inline-flex';
    } else {
      tabsContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
      plus.style.display = 'none';
      minus.style.display = 'inline-flex';
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.plus {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.minus {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.faq__panel {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="faq__tab">Question1
  <img src='img/plus.svg' alt="Show" class="plus">
  <img src='img/minus-svg.png' alt="Hide" class="minus">
</button>
<div class="faq__panel">
  <p>Answer1</p>
</div>

<button class="faq__tab">Question2
  <img src='img/plus.svg' alt="Show" class="plus">
  <img src='img/minus-svg.png' alt="Hide" class="minus">
</button>
<div class="faq__panel">
  <p>Answer2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working. I was missing one css style for faq__panel ,can you see original post again?

Comment: Still isn't working, because after clicking the first time it still says "Show" , at this point there should be the Hide text already.

Comment: @Dave, fixed that by interchanging the hide/show code block in if/else block, please check now:)

Comment: Thank you, works. Now I have 1 more issue, whenever I add more faq__tabs, the javascript effect is working only on first element, do you know maybe why?

Comment: @Dave, for that, instead of `document` object, you have look for the element (`.plus`, `.minus`) from current the `button` variable. Updated the answer with another block, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that you're setting image display to `flex`, either give the button `faq__tab` `display: flex` in the css file, or set `display: inline` to images

```
if (button.classList.contains('active-faq')) {
  tabsContent.style.maxHeight = tabsContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
   plus.style.display = 'none';
  minus.style.display = 'inline';
} else {
  tabsContent.style.maxHeight = 0;
  minus.style.display = 'none';
  plus.style.display = 'inline';
}
```